# How to solve quartic inequalities?

Tags: inequality

Could someone please explain to me how to solve quartic inequalities of the form  $$ax^4±bx^3±cx^2±dx±e \geq 0$$ or $$ax^4±bx^3±cx^2±dx±e \leq 0$$ ?

Comment: Well, first, you have to be able to solve the corresponding quartic equations. Can you do that?

Comment: I can solve quartic equations to some extent on account of there being available information on how to actually solve them, whereas I cannot find any information on solving quartic inequalities.

Comment: If you can solve polynomial equations, you can solve polynomial inequalities, as the only places the sign of the polynomial can change are at the roots.

Comment: As Travis commented, consider the sign of $a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4)$ where the $r_i$'s are the roots of the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here can you read how to solve the quartic http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html

Comment: I'm afraid I need to solve a quartic inequality, not equation.

Comment: solve the equation and then the inequality and thank you for the $-1$ if you have the solutions you can write $$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)>0$$